# How can I get multiplication between 2 different table columns with group by clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried this whole day but didn't got the result. Please go through the images on the link below

[Here is my table 1 structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lov8f.png)

[and here is my table 2 structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAOk8.png)

I want to multiply product_uom_qty from 1st table with cost in 2nd table and then group them by product_id which is there is both tables.

This is my query.

```
select sum(sale_order_line.product_uom_qty) * product_price_history.cost 
from sale_order_line, product_price_history
group by product_id;
```

And result I am getting is

> ERROR:  column reference "product_id" is ambiguous.  LINE 1: ...m
>   sale_order_line, product_price_history group by product_id...

please tell me where I am making mistake.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select product_id, sum(sol.product_uom_qty * pph.cost)
from sale_order_line sol join
     product_price_history pph
     using (product_id)
group by product_id;
```

That is, you need to join the tables on some condition.

Without sample data and desired results, it is unclear what you *really* want.  But this at least is a sensible query that removes the syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got the expected result. Sorry for not including desired result for me in the question. I will follow it from next. Thank you very much again.